# Trying to set Django and postgreSQL on Heroku

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku, osx-lion

I'm trying to follow the Heroku tutorial on deploying Django applications:

[Getting Started with Django on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django)

I'm able to run most of it without problems, but when it comes to synching the postgreSQL database I'm getting the following message:

```
psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

I've tried promoting databases,
seting the HOST to /tmp,
modifying the postgresql.conf,
and many other stuff I found searching around without success

I'm working on MB-Pro, Mac OS 10.7 (Lion), and read in some places that this OS was giving developers some headache when it comes to postgre. Did anyone have this problem on OS 10.7, and had it fixed after updating to 10.8? I'm considering updating in case it solves the problem.

Thank's in advance.

EDIT:

The command I'm trying to run is: `heroku run python manage.py syncdb`

EDIT:
I forgot to delete the DATABASE definition that was already defined on the file.

Comment: What Version of Postgres do you have locally and have you made sure, it is running?

Comment: Did you installed dj-database-url (is it listed in your requirements.txt?) and edited your setting such as explained there: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django#database-settings ?

Comment: I'm not sure I get it: is the problem happening when deploying your app on Heroku (as I assumed above), or is it not working locally ?

Comment: @AndreBossard I've tried the on homebrew, and also the app version of it available at the postgre site. And yes, i've made sure it was runing.

Comment: @niconoe Yes I did that! I'm able to deploy the app, but I cant sync database (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django#syncing-the-database)

Comment: On your laptop or on Heroku ?

Comment: Both, I can see the app running localhost (http://127.0.0.1:8000/) and also at: heroku open.

Comment: Just to be clear, I'm trying to run: heroku run python manage.py syncdb

Comment: Out of curiosity, did you replace your DATABASE variable with: 
import dj_database_url
DATABASES = {'default': dj_database_url.config(default='postgres://localhost')}

Comment: I fell dumb right now. I pasted the code, but forgot to remove the one that comes in the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to delete the DATABASE definition that was already defined on the file. It's working now.

Answer (score 0):

I made use of the [PostgresApp](http://postgresapp.com/) to help with running Postgres on my Mac and then in a terminal ran;

```
psql -h localhost
```